# Output gdbus to a file

Tags: ubuntu

The below script runs on Lock and UnLock.

`gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | grep LockedHint`

Gives this:

`/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'LockedHint': <true>}, @as []) /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'LockedHint': <false>}, @as [])`

How can I send the output to a file in the below format?

LogedInUserName;CurrentDateTime;SystemIP;SystemName;Lock
LogedInUserName;CurrentDateTime;SystemIP;SystemName;UnLock

Answer (score 0):

The below script will write the lock and UnLock to a file.

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | 
  while read x; do 
    case "$x" in 
        LockHint) 
          if [[ "$x" == "$lock" ]] ; then 
             echo "lock" >> /home/username/fileName.txt
          fi 
          if [[ "$x" == "$unLock" ]] ; then 
             echo "UnLock" >> /home/username/fileName.txt
          fi 
     ;; 
   esac
```